# Pulling Random Images From A Folder Above The public_html Folder

Tags: php, image, random, root, public-html

So I created an image.php file with this code and put it in my public_html folder:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile('home/folder/my image.jpg');
?>
```

and then I put this code in an html page in my public_html folder:

```
<img src="/image.php">
```

which perfectly displayed the "my image.jpg" file in  my browser when I loaded the page.  So this tells me that I do have access to the folder above my public_html folder (this is a dedicated server) and it tells me that I have no issues rendering a jpg file with spaces in the file name.

So now I'm trying to pull random images from the same folder, but can't seem to figure it out.  Here is what I am doing that is NOT working.

I've created an image.php file with this code and put in my public_html folder:

```
<?php

//Define Function to Select Random Image
function random_pic($dir = '/home/folder')
{
$files = glob($dir . '/*.jpg');
$file = array_rand($files);
return $files[$file];
}

//Select Random Image Path
$randPic = random_pic('/home/folder');

//Output Random Image When image.php is called from html image requests
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile($randPic);
?>
```

and then I put this code in an html page in my public_html folder:

```
<img src="/image.php">
```

Now when I load this html page with this img tag, I get nothing.  No error, no image, nothing but white space.  I appreciate any insight anyone can provide.

Comment: debugging steps: check that `glob()` is actually finding antyhing (e.g. `var_dump($files)`). Check that `random_pic()` is actually returning a path (e.g. `var_dump($randPic)`), then check that readfile isn't returning a boolean false (which you can't really var_dump, because the browser will try to read the dump text as image data).

Comment: do a file_exists($randPic); and echo $randPic... see if it makes sense.

Comment: In addition to what Marc said, I'd also consider adding a "no-cache" flag to the header so they don't get the same image each time.
Alternately, instead of using `readfile` you could use a `302 Temporary Redirect` and point directly to the image file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why not use an absolute path instead of**:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile('home/folder/my image.jpg');
```

**like this**:

```
// notice the absolute path prefix
if(!is_file($image_path = '/home/folder/my image.jpg')){
    header('Content-Type: text/plain', 404);
    echo 'Image file not found!';
}

// We got a file, keep going...
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($image_path));
readfile($image_path);

die; // done here
```

Or use the path relative to current directory of `.php` script with `__DIR__.'/path/to/image.jpg'`.

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand.  So with regard to pulliing a random image, instead of using this code:  

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    readfile($randPic);

I should be using something else?  It looks like you referenced my output code from my working solution and not from my non-working random image solution.  My apologies if I misunderstood.

Comment: @Bogarto You code is apparently good. You need to `var_dump($files)` inside the `random_pic` function and make sure you see anything listed by the `glob` result. That's why I thought the relative path may be an issue...

Answer (score 0):

You have to put safe_mode = off  or configure open_basedir to get access to the images directory.